# SWT Invalid thread access due to cocoa restrictions correction not working

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt, launch4j

I have a runnable simple **SWT jar file**. it runs fine on the mac terminal using **-XstartOnFirstThread**. I want to convert the jar file to an exe file with lauch4j and try to run it on a windows machine. Launch4j gives me the same error when am testing the project.

```
 **WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)** <br>
```

i guess its because its not fixed in the code yet.
below is the code for calling the main window

```
public void open() {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                display = Display.getDefault();
                createContents();
                shell.open();
                shell.layout();
                while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                        display.sleep();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me please?
thanks

Comment: You must arrange for launch4j to specify the -XstartOnFirstThread when it starts the JVM. There is nothing you can do in the Java code to work around that requirement because it is already too late when the Java starts to run. I don't use launch4j so I can't tell you how to do that. A more complex alternative is to write an Eclipse RCP, the executable generated from that runs correctly on macOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Could you suggest another tool I can use to create the executable and specify the XstartOnFirstThread option?